# How do yo add members/users to Rancher Project via POST request using python?

Tags: python, json, api, http, rancher

I'm able to create a rancher project via the rancher API using python, but can quite figure out how to do so to add users/members...?

Comment: Hi, please post the code you've written,  any error messages, the intended output, and how you've tried to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to 
   https://mycluster.com/v3/users
you can add/create another user and see the api/curl request to do so.

After you create the user you also need to add a globalrolebinding so that your user can login (and do other things).

https://mycluster.com/v3/globalrolebindings